# How I can remove all Google data from Youtube video downloads?

Tags: video, download, youtube, tracking

Just now I am reading one [question](https://superuser.com/questions/503834/watch-video-on-youtube-vs-use-download-tools-youtube-dl-is-network-traffic) here that Google is tracking all Youtube video's. In video files I am seeing this-

```
Same file 2 times

General
  Complete name : Video1.flv
  Format : Flash Video
  httphostheader : o-o---preferred---sn-huoa-qxae---v6---lscache5.c.youtube.com

General
  Complete name : Video1.flv
  Format : Flash Video
  httphostheader : o-o---preferred---sn-huoa-qxae---v11---lscache1.c.youtube.com
```

What means **httphostheader** (sometimes change)?

---

```
Same file 2 times

General
  Complete name : Video2.mp4
  Format : MPEG-4
  gsst : 0
  gstd : 42421
  gssd : BCA9FD844MM1352563445477621
  gshh : o-o---preferred---sn-huoa-qxae---v5---lscache8.c.youtube.com
Video #1
  Title : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v06.24.2007.
Audio #2
  Title : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v06.24.2007.

General
  Complete name : Video2.mp4
  Format : MPEG-4
  gsst : 0
  gstd : 42421
  gssd : BCA9FD844HH1352564824088190
  gshh : r2.cal01s03.c.youtube.com
Video #1
  Title : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v06.24.2007.
Audio #2
  Title : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v06.24.2007.
```

What means **gsst** (always same), **gstd** (always same), **gssd** (always change), **gshh** (sometimes change)?

---

```
General
  Complete name : Video3.3gp
  Format : MPEG-4
  gsst : 0
  gstd : 60500
  gssd : BCA9FD844HH1352565979202421
  gshh : o-o---preferred---sn-huoa-qxae---v1---lscache6.c.youtube.com
Video #1
  Title : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v06.24.2007.
Audio #2
  Title : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v06.24.2007.
```

---

```
General
  Complete name : Video4.webm
  Format : WebM
  Writing application : google
  Writing library : google
```

---

**How I can remove all Google data from Youtube video downloads? How I can do this for many video's at same time (can be from Windows program or console window)?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip metadata from all formats with FFmpeg](http://superuser.com/questions/441361/strip-metadata-from-all-formats-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: @techie007 I'm inclined to say this is a little more specific than just stripping the data, as the OP wants to know about what the metadata fields mean.

Answer (score 2):

This won't answer everything you're looking for but I hope it helps.

**In terms of removing the data**: I guess check out [Strip metadata from all formats with FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/441361/strip-metadata-from-all-formats-with-ffmpeg)  as techie007 said. I suppose, best to just remux the A/V into a fresh new container and specify to only copy the a/v data (read [here](http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/172509-howto-remove-meta-info-about-mp4-flv-file-downloaded-off-youtube.html)).

**In terms of what the data means:**

Cross-referencing mp4 and FLV files (of the same uploaded video), it seems **gshh** = **httphostheader**. And thus, **'gs'** I'm guessing might mean 'google services' or 'google server'.

Its value, is what's at the beginning of the hidden URL location of the FLV or MP4 file in question. It's the actual HTTP server location that the YouTube video player calls up in question.

E.g., for [this](http://vg.vc/vid/MNT_vs.%20Germany_Germany_Own_Goal_-_June_2,_2013.mp4) extracted YouTube mp4 file, the **gshh** value is **r6---sn-u5a3u5a3-aige.c.youtube.com**.

The full url for the mp4 file (obtained by [Keepvid.com](http://keepvid.com/), or as a possible alternative, [GetFLV](http://www.getflv.net/)), is [this](http://vg.vc/paste/9j23r0).

So in other words, **gssh** or **httphostheader** seems to be a record of the server that your video was uploaded to (and stays on, unless, I assume, it's moved for some reason). It seems that Google stamp all MP4, FLV and 3GP files ([including the original one you upload](https://superuser.com/questions/603243/when-extracting-a-youtube-video-is-there-a-way-to-know-what-format-was-the-orig)) with this record of the server location, and we observe interestingly that Google doesn't for any WebM files.

As for **gsst**, **gstd**, and **gssd**: it appears no one has figured those ones out on the internet. Here's [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281659/what-do-mp4-metadata-tags-such-as-gssd-or-gsst-mean/14596664#14596664) [links](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?p=46046149) to check out, but they just conjecture like me and don't bring anything new to the table. (Only that we definitely know what gshh is.)